# Is it possible to place custom post type files inside a folder in theme directory?

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, themes, directory

I have created a custom post type called `customtype`. From my understanding the template file for it would be `single-customtype.php` which is placed inside `wp-content/themes/mytheme`.

Can I place the `single-customtype.php` file inside a custom folder in the theme directory? It's not critical but would help with theme files organization.

This is what I want to achieve:
`wp-content/themes/mytheme/customtype/single-customtype.php`

Comment: I don't think this is going to be easy to do - you're essentially rewriting a part of WP's template architecture. I think these files would have to remain in your theme root, but as an answer states, you can use `get_template_part()` to split reusable bits of code up, including into subfolders.

Comment: You can do it, but it's questionable as to whether it's worthwhile.  Have a look at my answer to a similar question yesterday: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/227006/how-to-move-page-template-to-custom-folder/227053#227053

If you're up for the challenge when you've seen that, I can help you modify that answer for your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look at the TwentySixteen theme, which does it this way:

In `single.php`:

`get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'single' );`

Several templates are grouped in the 'template-parts' folder. You could use a similar logic for your custom post type.

It seems that the technique comes from [_underscores](https://github.com/Automattic/_s).

Comment: `single-customtype.php` will still remain in the main directory (I was hoping to move `archive-customtype.php` as well) I'm more concerned about the main files than template parts but this will help a bit.